# Prove $\sim$ is an equivalence relation: $x \sim y$ if and only if $y = 3^kx$, where $k$ is a real number

Tags: relations

The relation $\sim$ is defined on $\mathbb{Z}^+$ (all positive integers). We say $x\sim y$ if and only if $y=3^kx$ for some real number $k$.

I need to prove that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.

To prove an equivalence relation we must certify that:

- It is reflexive
- It is symmetric
- It is transitive

I am not sure how to start this off since if I want to prove for:

**Reflexive:** I would replace $y$ with $x$, so that $x = (3^k)*x$ which is a positive integer when $k > 0$. Thus $x \sim x$ and $\sim$ is reflexive (?).

**Symmetric:** Suppose $x \sim y$ so that $y = (3^k)*x$ then $x = (3^k)*y$ is also an element of $\mathbb{Z}^+$. Thus $y \sim x$ and $\sim$ is symmetric (?).

**Transitive:** I'm not too sure about this last one. I think my entire proof is wrong anyways.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: for reflexive set k=0

Comment: It does make sense if you define the relation more unambiguously than you did. What you meant is probably "x~y if and only if there is a real number $k$ such that $y=3^kx$. If that's the relation then "x~x if and only if there is a real number $k$ such that $x=3^kx$" makes perfect sense.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant thank you.

Comment: Please make the bodies of your posts self-contained. The key information about $\sim$ was hidden in the title; you should *not* rely on the title to provide necessary information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what needs to be shown in order to show that something is an equivalence relation. None of the arguments you present is a valid argument for the proposition you are trying to establish.

Your equivalence relation is defined on the set of positive integers. So if you write $x\sim y$, you are already assuming that $x$ and $y$ are positive integers, there is no need to prove that they are.

The relation is defined as follows: if $x$ and $y$ are positive integers, then
$$x\sim y\Longleftrightarrow \text{there exists a real number }k\text{ such that }y = 3^kx.$$

That means that in order to show that two given numbers $x$ and $y$ are related, then you need to produce a real number $k$ that *witnesses* the identity $y=3^kx$. For example, to show that $y=9$ and $x=3$ are related, I just need to say: "take $k=1$. Then $9 = 3^1\cdot 3$; that is, $y = 3^1x$, so $x\sim y$ holds." To show that $18\sim 6$, I say "take $k=-1$; then $6 = 3^{-1}(18)$ holds." Etc.

And if you know that $x\sim y$, then you know that there exists a real number $k$ such that $y=3^kx$.

Thus, to show that $\sim$ is reflexive, you need to show that given any positive integer $x$, you can find a real number $k$ (which may depend on $x$) such that $x = 3^k x$. You *need* to say who $k$ is. Your argument about "being positive when $k\gt 0$" doesn't get you there in any way.

To  show that $\sim$ is symmetric, you have to show that **if** you already know that $x\sim y$, so that you *know* there is a real number $k$ such that $y=3^k x$, **then** you can find some real number $\ell$ such that $x=3^{\ell}y$. This will witness the fact that $y\sim x$ holds, showing symmetry. *You already know that* $x$ *and* $y$ *are positive integers*. You know that simply because you know that $x\sim y$ holds, and that means that $x$ and $y$ have to be positive integers in the first place.

To show that $\sim$ is transitive, you have to show that **if** you already know $x\sim y$ and $y\sim z$, then you can exhibit a real number $r$ such that $z=3^rx$; this will witness $x\sim z$. You *know* there is a real number $k$ such that $y=3^kx$ (because $x\sim y$); and you *know* there is a real number $\ell$ such that $z=3^{\ell}y$ (because $y\sim z$); now you need to produce that number $r$ somehow. Again, *you already know that* $x$, $y$, *and* $z$ *are positive integers*, because you already know that $x\sim y$ and $y\sim z$ are true, which means, *inter alia,* that $x$, $y$, and $z$ are all positive integers.

Comment: Very well worded and explained, thank you so much.

Answer (score 8):

Isn't this relation true for all $x,y$ with the same sign? Since $3^k$, $k$ in reals, can take any positive real number?

Comment: sorry, didnt see that x,y had to be in Z+.

Comment: There is no need to be sorry, the answer to the question as stated was perfectly correct. I would guess, however, that the real question is the following. Define the relation $\equiv$ on the positive integers by $x \equiv y$ if there is an integer $k$ (positive, negative, or $0$) such that $y=(3^k)x$. Show that $\equiv$ is an equivalence relation.

Comment: This allows an alternative proof:  as $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{Z}^+ x \sim y$, the three requirements for an equivalence relation are easily verified.

Comment: my answer was added before an edit where I believe the extra condition was entered. if x,y are in reals, this should be equivilent to saying $x \sim y \leftrightarrow x,y>0$  OR  $x,y<0$ OR $x=y=0$ right? since  for all r in reals there exists a k s.t $3^k = r$ and signs are kept when a real is multiplied by a positive real.

Answer (score 4):

Put $\rm\: G = \{ 3^r\: :\: r\in \mathbb R\}\:.\:$ It's reflexive by $\rm\: x/x = 1\in G\:.\:$ It's symmetric by $\rm\:G\:$ is closed under inverses $\rm\ x/y \in G\ \Rightarrow\ y/x\in G\:.\ $ It's transitive by $\rm\:G\:$ is closed under products $\rm\ x/y,\ y/z \in G\ \Rightarrow\ x/z \in G\:.\:$

Therefore the proof requires only that $\rm\:G\:$ contains $1\:$ and is closed under products and inverses or, equivalently, that $\rm\:G\:$ is nonempty and $\rm\:G\:$ is closed under quotients, i.e. $\rm\:G\:$ is a commutative *group*. This equivalence relation (congruence) will come to the fore when you study *quotient groups*.

Comment: Why did you change the set $G$ to $\{3^r : r \in \mathbb R\}$?  The title of this post is incorrect, as $k$ is meant to be an integer.

Comment: @DJC: Both relations are equivalence relations; while it is possible (nay, likely) the original was meant to be that $k$ is an integer, the OP said "real number" from his very first edit. Bill edited his post to reflect the question asked, not the hypothetical question "meant to be asked".

Comment: @DJC: I changed it to be consistent with the titled problem. Why do you believe the title is incorrect? Either interpretation works.

Comment: I figured the title of this post was incorrect as the case $k in \mathbb{R}$ is trivial.  I was just curious why you edited your post.

Answer (score 3):

My short answer:

Reflexive: $k = 0$.

Symmetric: negate $k$ - $y = 3^k x \Longleftrightarrow x = 3^{-k} y$.

Transitive:  $y = 3^k x$ and $z = 3^h y \Longrightarrow z = 3^{k+h} x$.

I don't see why there is anything more to it than this.